# Limiting certain commands to certain channels [Discord.js]

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I have only found answers to this question for discord.js with commando which won't work with just discord.js

I want to limit an automated reaction to any attachment send in one channel. (And only in that one channel.) So doing it with roles won't work.

Kind regards Per.

Comment: How do you add that reaction, attach some code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want that a command can only be done in a certain channel you can check if the id of the channel were the message was sent is the id you have stored to allow the command to be done

```
if(message.channel.id === 'id of channel'){
//code of command
}
```

Comment: And when i want to limit it to 2 channels? what do i have to add?

Comment: in that case you use OR operator to check if the channel is A or B

"   if(message.channel.id === 'id of channel A' || message.channel.id === 'id of channel B'){//code of command
}   "